# how to identify which instance of viewpart is running in eclipse rcp application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

i have multiple instances of view  open in my eclipse rcp application. Can any one tell me how can i identify which instance of viewpart is running. and also how can i switch to different instances of same ViewId programmatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have set `allowMultiple` in the view declaration.

Use `getViewSite().getSecondaryId()` in your code to get the secondary id of the current view.

And use `IWorkbenchPage.showView(String viewId, String secondaryId, int mode)` to activate a different view...

Comment: But now i m getting another problem is that when i use IWorkbenchPage.showView(String viewId, String secondaryId, int mode) its loading whole class again, so it makes whole process again which it has done for preivous one.